DAX Dynamic Measure as a Slicer in Power BI
I am trying to create a slicer in Power BI. This slicer is based on the selected value. As a result I want to get the results of 'WeekFilter' as my Slicer. But unfortunately Power BI won't let me, whereas I can make a slicer of 'Weekberekeningen' and 'Volgorde'. See screenshots:


My current Dax measure for WeekFilter (which works perfectly) is the following:
WeekFilter = 
VAR WeekNr = SELECTEDVALUE(Weekkeuze[WeekNr])
VAR Ord = SELECTEDVALUE(TI[Volgorde])
RETURN
IF(
    Ord = 0, "Deze week",
    IF(Ord = -1, "Vorige week",
"Week " & WeekNr + Ord))

So the selected week should influence the output in the slicer for the previous weeks.
As an example: I select week 10. Then WeekFilter gives the following results: 'Deze week', 'Vorige week', Week 8, Week 7, Week 6
What do I have to change so I can apply the result of WeekFilter as a slicer?

what is the weeknum column? could you pls porivde more details on  'the selected week should influence the output in the slicer for the previous weeks? what's the expected output?

I just added an example in the post

This is the sample data I used for testing.



week
weeknum




week1
1


week2
2


week3
3


week4
4


week5
5


week6
6


week7
7


week8
8


week9
9


week10
10


week11
11



create the same table for filtering. Do not create relationship between two tables
Table 2 = 'Table'

Then create a measure and add the measure to visual filter to get the 5 weeks output.
MEASURE =
IF (
    MAX ( 'Table'[weeknum] ) <= MAX ( 'Table 2'[weeknum] )
        && MAX ( 'Table'[weeknum] )
            >= MAX ( 'Table 2'[weeknum] ) - 4,
    1
)


At last, you create a measure
MEASURE 2 =
IF (
    MAX ( 'Table'[weeknum] ) = MAX ( 'Table 2'[weeknum] ),
    "Deze week",
    IF (
        MAX ( 'Table'[weeknum] )
            = MAX ( 'Table 2'[weeknum] ) - 1,
        "Vorige week",
        MAX ( 'Table'[weeknum] )
    )
)


